# Running SEMAFOR semantic parser throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, nlp

For a project I am currently working on, I need to annotate sentences with FrameNet annotations. This is achieved well by the SEMAFOR semantic parser (https://github.com/Noahs-ARK/semafor). I installed and configured this tool as described on the git repository. However, if I run the runSemafor.sh script with the cygwin terminal, it throws and IllegalArgumentException indicating that the generated pos.tagged file cannot be parsed.

Here is the complete console output in cygwin (running it on windows):

```
$ ./runSemafor.sh D:/XFrame/Libs/Semafor/semafor/temp/sample.txt  D:/XFrame/Libs/Semafor/semafor/temp/output 2

**********************************************************************
Tokenizing file: D:/XFrame/Libs/Semafor/semafor/temp/neu.txt

real    0m0.140s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.108s
Finished tokenization.
**********************************************************************


**********************************************************************
Part-of-speech tagging tokenized data....
/cygdrive/d/XFrame/Libs/Semafor/semafor/scripts/jmx/cygdrive/d/XFrame/Libs/Semafor/semafor/bin
Read 11692 items from tagger.project/word.voc
Read 45 items from tagger.project/tag.voc
Read 42680 items from tagger.project/tagfeatures.contexts
Read 42680 contexts, 117558 numFeatures from tagger.project/tagfeatures.fmap
Read model tagger.project/model : numPredictions=45, numParams=117558
Read tagdict from tagger.project/tagdict
*This is MXPOST (Version 1.0)*
*Copyright (c) 1997 Adwait Ratnaparkhi*
Sentence: 0 Length: 9 Elapsed Time: 0.007 seconds.

real    0m0.762s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.171s
/cygdrive/d/XFrame/Libs/Semafor/semafor/bin
Finished part-of-speech tagging tokenized data.
**********************************************************************
**********************************************************************
Converting postagged input to conll.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.SentenceCodec.decode(Sentence                                                                              Codec.java:83)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.SentenceCodec$SentenceIterato                                                                              r.computeNext(SentenceCodec.java:115)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.SentenceCodec$SentenceIterato                                                                              r.computeNext(SentenceCodec.java:100)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractI                                                                              terator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.j                                                                              ava:138)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.ConvertFormat.convertStream(C                                                                              onvertFormat.java:94)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.ConvertFormat.main(ConvertFor                                                                              mat.java:76)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PosToken must have 2 "_"-separate                                                                              d fields
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java                                                                              :92)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.Token.fromPosTagged(Token.jav                                                                              a:248)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.SentenceCodec$2.decodeToken(S                                                                              entenceCodec.java:28)
    at edu.cmu.cs.lti.ark.fn.data.prep.formats.SentenceCodec.decode(Sentence                                                                              Codec.java:79)
    ... 6 more
```

As a sample file for the annotation I use the sample file from the repository:

```
This is a test for SEMAFOR, a frame-semantic parser.
This is just a dummy line.
There's a Santa Claus!
```

The generated pos.tagged file however looks as if there is no error. Why does this exception occur?

```
This_DT is_VBZ a_DT test_NN for_IN SEMAFOR_NNP ,_, a_DT frame-semantic_JJ parser_NN ._. 
This_DT is_VBZ just_RB a_DT dummy_JJ line_NN ._. 
There_EX 's_VBZ a_DT Santa_NNP Claus_NNP !_.
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the parser but have you tried tracing the line back into the source code?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't manage to solve this issue. It seems that it has some problems with finding the files because of using cygwin. In the end I set up an ubuntu system, where it works perfectly fine for me and wrote some java code, giving me programmatic access to the the parser. If you are interested in this, I can share the code with you.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the exactly same issue as you stated, and solved it moments ago by myself. It is because that the parser only takes the right formatted input file with one sentence per line.

What you need to do is: when writing each sentence into the file, add the following lines in your codes, to remove line breakers or tabs. Then you should be good to go!

```
line = line.replace('\n', '')
line = line.replace('\t', '')
```